# Apollo local query not working with variable

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm using React Apollo to manage local state in my application and am trying to run a query of my state but with passing a variable as per their [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readquery)

Here is my setup:

**default state**

```
const defaults {
  myItems: [
    {
      __typename: 'Item',
      itemId: '1'
    },
    {
      __typename: 'Item',
      itemId: '2'
    }
  ]
}
```

**My component**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const LOCAL_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query LOCAL_ITEMS_QUERY($itemId: String){
    myItems(itemId: $itemId) @client {
      __typename
      itemId
    }
  }
`;

class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Query query={LOCAL_ITEMS_QUERY} variables={{ itemId: '1' }}>
          {myItems=> {
            console.log(myItems)
            return <div />
          }}
        </Query>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

The above query in the component `MyComponent` returns the array with both items in there as opposed to just the item with an itemId of `'1'`.

Where have I gone wrong here? It seems as though it's possible to query the local state with variables but not sure why its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should query for single `Item`, like

```
const LOCAL_ITEM_QUERY = gql`
  query LOCAL_ITEM_QUERY($itemId: String){
    Item(id: $itemId) @client {
      __typename
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

... but it depends on type definitions.

Notice that `id` and `__typename` are used as key in cache - not any custom named `itemId`. Read [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#cache-redirects-with-cacheredirects)

Local state (with `@client`) data is documented [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/) - local resolver can be required for access by id or other fields.